# STLLoader does not create valid geometry for STLExporter

Tags: three.js

I am using the STLLoader to import models into a scene that also has other objects. After that, I export the entire scene using STLExporter. Any STL models previously imported does not appear to export with the rest of the scene. Why is that and how can I make it work?

In addition to three.min.js, the following libraries were also used:

```
STLExporter.js
STLLoader.js
fileSaver.js
```

Import:

```
var stlLoader = new THREE.STLLoader();
stlLoader.load( 'models/anymodel.stl', function ( geometry ) {
    var model = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    model.position.set(0, 0, 0);
    model.name="model"
    scene.add(model);
})
```

Export:

```
var exporter = new THREE.STLExporter();
var txt = exporter.parse(scene);
var blob = new Blob([txt], { type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8" });
saveAs(blob, "export.stl");
```

In the STLExporter, there is a line that checks if an object is valid geometry. If not, the object is skipped. A model imported with STLLoader does not appear have valid geometry.

Comment: Can you add some example code?